Simple zip lib like experiment
Code review would be appreciated.
Nothing heroic. Very trivial implementation of Adaptive Huffman Coding, LZ77 compression and deflate coding by the book:
https://github.com/leok7v/sqz
Reason for implementation, just my personal refresher of well known algorithms.
Performance or compression rate were no goals, simplicity was.
Sometimes I need "zip/unzip" functionality in a tiny project and do not want to bring external dependency to zlib and/or build it for all platforms.
Well aware that almost all modern OS have LZMA/ZIP practically out of the box (since they all use it internally) and way better maintained libs exists.
I hope there is less than 99 huge ugly bugs in the code.
squeeze.h
#ifndef squeeze_header_included
#define squeeze_header_included

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

enum {
    squeeze_deflate_sym_min   = 257, // minimum literal for length base
    squeeze_deflate_sym_max   = 284, // maximum literal for length base
    squeeze_deflate_pos_max   = 29,   // maximum pos base index
    squeeze_deflate_len_min   = 3,
    // value is the same but unrelated to squeeze_deflate_sym_min:
    squeeze_deflate_len_max   = 257
};

enum { // "nyt" stands for Not Yet Transmitted (see Vitter Algorithm)
    squeeze_min_win_bits  =  10,
    squeeze_max_win_bits  =  15,
    squeeze_lit_nyt       =  squeeze_deflate_sym_max + 1,
    squeeze_pos_nyt       =  squeeze_deflate_pos_max + 1,
};

// deflate tables

static const uint16_t squeeze_len_base[29] = {
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, // 257-264
    11, 13, 15, 17,          // 265-268
    19, 23, 27, 31,          // 269-272
    35, 43, 51, 59,          // 273-276
    67, 83, 99, 115,         // 277-280
    131, 163, 195, 227, 258  // 281-285
};

static const uint8_t squeeze_len_xb[29] = { // extra bits
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 257-264
    1, 1, 1, 1,             // 265-268
    2, 2, 2, 2,             // 269-272
    3, 3, 3, 3,             // 273-276
    4, 4, 4, 4,             // 277-280
    5, 5, 5, 5, 0           // 281-285 (len = 258 has no extra bits)
};

static const uint16_t squeeze_pos_base[30] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4,  // 0-3
    5, 7,        // 4-5
    9, 13,       // 6-7
    17, 25,      // 8-9
    33, 49,      // 10-11
    65, 97,      // 12-13
    129, 193,    // 14-15
    257, 385,    // 16-17
    513, 769,    // 18-19
    1025, 1537,  // 20-21
    2049, 3073,  // 22-23
    4097, 6145,  // 24-25
    8193, 12289, // 26-27
    16385, 24577 // 28-29
};

static const uint8_t squeeze_pos_xb[30] = { // extra bits
    0, 0, 0, 0, // 0-3
    1, 1,       // 4-5
    2, 2,       // 6-7
    3, 3,       // 8-9
    4, 4,       // 10-11
    5, 5,       // 12-13
    6, 6,       // 14-15
    7, 7,       // 16-17
    8, 8,       // 18-19
    9, 9,       // 20-21
    10, 10,     // 22-23
    11, 11,     // 24-25
    12, 12,     // 26-27
    13, 13      // 28-29
};

typedef struct huffman_node {
    uint64_t freq;
    uint64_t path;
    int32_t  bits; // 0 for root
    int32_t  pix;  // parent
    int32_t  lix;  // left
    int32_t  rix;  // right
} huffman_node;

typedef struct huffman_tree {
    huffman_node* node;
    int32_t n;
    int32_t next;  // next non-terminal nodes in the tree >= n
    int32_t depth; // max tree depth seen
    int32_t complete; // tree is too deep or freq too high - no more updates
    // stats:
    struct {
        size_t updates;
        size_t swaps;
        size_t moves;
    } stats;
} huffman_tree;

typedef struct bitstream {
    void*    stream; // stream and (data,capacity) are exclusive
    uint8_t* data;
    uint64_t capacity; // data[capacity]
    uint64_t bytes; // number of bytes written
    uint64_t read;  // number of bytes read
    uint64_t b64;   // bit shifting buffer
    int32_t  bits;  // bit count inside b64
    errno_t  error; // sticky error
    errno_t (*output)(struct bitstream* bs); // write b64 as 8 bytes
    errno_t (*input)(struct bitstream* bs);  // read b64 as 8 bytes
} bitstream;

typedef struct {
    errno_t error; // sticky
    huffman_tree lit; // 0..255 literal bytes; 257-285 length
    huffman_tree pos; // positions tree of 1^win_bits
    huffman_node lit_nodes[512 * 2 - 1];
    huffman_node pos_nodes[32 * 2 - 1];
    bitstream*         bs;
    uint8_t len_index[squeeze_deflate_sym_max + 1]; // index squeeze_len_base
    uint8_t pos_index[1u << 15];                    // index squeeze_pos_base
} squeeze_type;

typedef struct {
    void (*init)(squeeze_type* s);
    // `win_bits` is a log2 of window size in bytes in range
    // [squeeze_min_win_bits..squeeze_max_win_bits]
    void (*write_header)(bitstream* bs, uint64_t bytes);
    void (*compress)(squeeze_type* s, bitstream* bs,
                     const uint8_t* data, size_t bytes, uint16_t window);
    void (*read_header)(bitstream* bs, uint64_t *bytes);
    void (*decompress)(squeeze_type* s, bitstream* bs,
                       uint8_t* data, size_t bytes);
} squeeze_interface;

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" squeeze_interface squeeze;
#else
extern squeeze_interface squeeze;
#endif

#endif // squeeze_header_included

#if defined(squeeze_implementation) && !defined(squeeze_implemented)

#define squeeze_implemented

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899757/how-can-i-use-nullptr-for-null-pointers-prior-to-c23

#ifndef null
#define null ((void*)0) // like null_ptr better than NULL (0)
#endif

#ifndef countof
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
#endif

#ifndef assert
#include <assert.h>
#endif
#include <string.h>

static inline void     bitstream_create(bitstream* bs, void* data,
                                                       size_t capacity);
static inline void     bitstream_write_bit(bitstream* bs, int32_t bit);
static inline void     bitstream_write_bits(bitstream* bs, uint64_t data,
                                                           int32_t bits);
static inline int      bitstream_read_bit(bitstream* bs); // bool 0|1 "int"
static inline uint64_t bitstream_read_bits(bitstream* bs, int32_t bits);
static inline void     bitstream_flush(bitstream* bs); // write trailing zeros
static inline void     bitstream_dispose(bitstream* bs);

static inline void bitstream_write_bit(bitstream* bs, int32_t bit) {
    if (bs->error == 0) {
        bs->b64 <<= 1;
        bs->b64 |= (bit & 1);
        bs->bits++;
        if (bs->bits == 64) {
            if (bs->data != null && bs->capacity > 0) {
                assert(bs->stream == null);
                for (int i = 0; i < 8 && bs->error == 0; i++) {
                    if (bs->bytes == bs->capacity) {
                        bs->error = E2BIG;
                    } else {
                        uint8_t b = (uint8_t)(bs->b64 >> ((7 - i) * 8));
                        bs->data[bs->bytes++] = b;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                assert(bs->data == null && bs->capacity == 0);
                bs->error = bs->output(bs);
                if (bs->error == 0) { bs->bytes += 8; }
            }
            bs->bits = 0;
            bs->b64 = 0;
        }
    }
}

static inline void bitstream_write_bits(bitstream* bs,
                                        uint64_t data, int32_t bits) {
    assert(0 < bits && bits <= 64);
    while (bits > 0 && bs->error == 0) {
        bitstream_write_bit(bs, data & 1);
        bits--;
        data >>= 1;
    }
}

static inline int bitstream_read_bit(bitstream* bs) {
    int bit = 0;
    if (bs->error == 0) {
        if (bs->bits == 0) {
            bs->b64 = 0;
            if (bs->data != null && bs->bytes > 0) {
                assert(bs->stream == null);
                for (int i = 0; i < 8 && bs->error == 0; i++) {
                    if (bs->read == bs->bytes) {
                        bs->error = E2BIG;
                    } else {
                        const uint64_t byte = (bs->data[bs->read] & 0xFF);
                        bs->b64 |= byte << ((7 - i) * 8);
                        bs->read++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                assert(bs->data == null && bs->bytes == 0);
                bs->error = bs->input(bs);
                if (bs->error == 0) { bs->read += 8; }
            }
            bs->bits = 64;
        }
        bit = ((int64_t)bs->b64) < 0; // same as (bs->b64 >> 63) & 1;
        bs->b64 <<= 1;
        bs->bits--;
    }
    return bit;
}

static inline uint64_t bitstream_read_bits(bitstream* bs, int32_t bits) {
    uint64_t data = 0;
    assert(0 < bits && bits <= 64);
    for (int32_t b = 0; b < bits && bs->error == 0; b++) {
        int bit = bitstream_read_bit(bs);
        if (bit) { data |= ((uint64_t)bit) << b; }
    }
    return data;
}

static inline void bitstream_create(bitstream* bs, void* data, size_t bytes) {
    assert(bs->data != null);
    memset(bs, 0x00, sizeof(*bs));
    bs->data = (uint8_t*)data;
    bs->capacity = bytes;
}

static inline void bitstream_flush(bitstream* bs) {
    while (bs->bits > 0 && bs->error == 0) { bitstream_write_bit(bs, 0); }
}

static inline void bitstream_dispose(bitstream* bs) {
    memset(bs, 0x00, sizeof(*bs));
}

// Huffman Adaptive Coding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding

static inline void   huffman_init(huffman_tree* t, huffman_node nodes[],
                                                   const size_t m);
static inline bool   huffman_insert(huffman_tree* t, int32_t i);
static inline bool   huffman_inc_frequency(huffman_tree* t, int32_t symbol);
static inline double huffman_entropy(const huffman_tree* t); // Shannon (bps)

static void huffman_update_paths(huffman_tree* t, int32_t i) {
    t->stats.updates++;
    const int32_t m = t->n * 2 - 1;
    if (i == m - 1) { t->depth = 0; } // root
    const int32_t  bits = t->node[i].bits;
    const uint64_t path = t->node[i].path;
    assert(bits < (int32_t)sizeof(uint64_t) * 8 - 1);
    assert((path & (~((1ULL << (bits + 1)) - 1))) == 0);
    const int32_t lix = t->node[i].lix;
    const int32_t rix = t->node[i].rix;
    if (lix != -1) {
        t->node[lix].bits = bits + 1;
        t->node[lix].path = path;
        huffman_update_paths(t, lix);
    }
    if (rix != -1) {
        t->node[rix].bits = bits + 1;
        t->node[rix].path = path | (1ULL << bits);
        huffman_update_paths(t, rix);
    }
    if (bits > t->depth) { t->depth = bits; }
}

static inline int32_t huffman_swap_siblings(huffman_tree* t,
                                            const int32_t i) {
    const int32_t m = t->n * 2 - 1;
    assert(0 <= i && i < m);
    if (i < m - 1) { // not root
        const int32_t pix = t->node[i].pix;
        assert(pix >= t->n); // parent (cannot be a leaf)
        const int32_t lix = t->node[pix].lix;
        const int32_t rix = t->node[pix].rix;
        if (lix >= 0 && rix >= 0) {
            assert(0 <= lix && lix < m - 1 && 0 <= rix && rix < m - 1);
            if (t->node[lix].freq > t->node[rix].freq) { // swap
                t->stats.swaps++;
                t->node[pix].lix = rix;
                t->node[pix].rix = lix;
                // because swap changed all path below:
                huffman_update_paths(t, pix);
                return i == lix ? rix : lix;
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}

static inline void huffman_frequency_changed(huffman_tree* t, int32_t ix);

static inline void huffman_update_freq(huffman_tree* t, int32_t i) {
    const int32_t lix = t->node[i].lix;
    const int32_t rix = t->node[i].rix;
    assert(lix != -1 || rix != -1); // at least one leaf present
    t->node[i].freq = (lix >= 0 ? t->node[lix].freq : 0) +
                      (rix >= 0 ? t->node[rix].freq : 0);
}

static inline void huffman_move_up(huffman_tree* t, int32_t ix) {
    const int32_t pix = t->node[ix].pix; // parent
    assert(pix != -1);
    const int32_t gix = t->node[pix].pix; // grandparent
    assert(gix != -1);
    assert(t->node[pix].rix == ix);
    // Is parent grandparent`s left or right child?
    const bool parent_is_left_child = pix == t->node[gix].lix;
    const int32_t psx = parent_is_left_child ? // parent sibling index
        t->node[gix].rix : t->node[gix].lix;   // aka auntie/uncle
    if (t->node[ix].freq > t->node[psx].freq) {
        // Move grandparents left or right subtree to be
        // parents right child instead of 'i'.
        t->stats.moves++;
        t->node[ix].pix = gix;
        if (parent_is_left_child) {
            t->node[gix].rix = ix;
        } else {
            t->node[gix].lix = ix;
        }
        t->node[pix].rix = psx;
        t->node[psx].pix = pix;
        huffman_update_freq(t, pix);
        huffman_update_freq(t, gix);
        huffman_swap_siblings(t, ix);
        huffman_swap_siblings(t, psx);
        huffman_swap_siblings(t, pix);
        huffman_update_paths(t, gix);
        huffman_frequency_changed(t, gix);
    }
}

static inline void huffman_frequency_changed(huffman_tree* t, int32_t i) {
    const int32_t m = t->n * 2 - 1; (void)m;
    const int32_t pix = t->node[i].pix;
    if (pix == -1) { // `i` is root
        assert(i == m - 1);
        huffman_update_freq(t, i);
        i = huffman_swap_siblings(t, i);
    } else {
        assert(0 <= pix && pix < m);
        huffman_update_freq(t, pix);
        i = huffman_swap_siblings(t, i);
        huffman_frequency_changed(t, pix);
    }
    if (pix != -1 && t->node[pix].pix != -1 && i == t->node[pix].rix) {
        assert(t->node[i].freq >= t->node[t->node[pix].lix].freq);
        huffman_move_up(t, i);
    }
}

static bool huffman_insert(huffman_tree* t, int32_t i) {
    bool done = true;
    const int32_t root = t->n * 2 - 1 - 1;
    int32_t ipx = root;
    assert(t->node[i].pix == -1 && t->node[i].lix == -1 && t->node[i].rix == -1);
    assert(t->node[i].freq == 0 && t->node[i].bits == 0 && t->node[i].path == 0);
    t->node[i].freq = 1;
    while (ipx >= t->n) {
        if (t->node[ipx].rix == -1) {
            t->node[ipx].rix = i;
            t->node[i].pix = ipx;
            break;
        } else if (t->node[ipx].lix == -1) {
            t->node[ipx].lix = i;
            t->node[i].pix = ipx;
            break;
        } else {
            assert(t->node[ipx].lix >= 0);
            assert(t->node[i].freq <= t->node[t->node[ipx].lix].freq);
            ipx = t->node[ipx].lix;
        }
    }
    if (ipx >= t->n) { // not a leaf, inserted
        t->node[ipx].freq++;
        i = huffman_swap_siblings(t, i);
        assert(t->node[ipx].lix == i || t->node[ipx].rix);
        assert(t->node[ipx].freq ==
                (t->node[ipx].rix >= 0 ? t->node[t->node[ipx].rix].freq : 0) +
                (t->node[ipx].lix >= 0 ? t->node[t->node[ipx].lix].freq : 0));
    } else { // leaf
        assert(t->next > t->n);
        if (t->next == t->n) {
            done = false; // cannot insert
            t->complete = true;
        } else {
            t->next--;
            int32_t nix = t->next;
            t->node[nix] = (huffman_node){
                .freq = t->node[ipx].freq,
                .lix = ipx,
                .rix = -1,
                .pix = t->node[ipx].pix,
                .bits = t->node[ipx].bits,
                .path = t->node[ipx].path
            };
            if (t->node[ipx].pix != -1) {
                if (t->node[t->node[ipx].pix].lix == ipx) {
                    t->node[t->node[ipx].pix].lix = nix;
                } else {
                    t->node[t->node[ipx].pix].rix = nix;
                }
            }
            t->node[ipx].pix = nix;
            t->node[ipx].bits++;
            t->node[ipx].path = t->node[nix].path;
            t->node[nix].rix = i;
            t->node[i].pix = nix;
            t->node[i].bits = t->node[nix].bits + 1;
            t->node[i].path = t->node[nix].path | (1ULL << t->node[nix].bits);
            huffman_update_freq(t, nix);
            ipx = nix;
        }
    }
    huffman_frequency_changed(t, i);
    huffman_update_paths(t, ipx);
    assert(t->node[i].freq != 0 && t->node[i].bits != 0);
    return done;
}

// If input literal frequencies are severely skewed (e.g. Lucas numbers
// similar to Fibonacci numbers) and input sequence is long enough.
// The depth of the tree will grow past 64 bits.
// The first Lucas number that exceeds 2^64 is
// L(81) = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 not actually realistic but
// better be safe than sorry

// huffman_inc_frequency() returns false on conditions inability to insert
// new node and tree being too deep of frequency too high
// The inability to insert new node should be treated as fatal outside
// huffman_inc_frequency() call.

static inline bool huffman_inc_frequency(huffman_tree* t, int32_t i) {
    bool done = true;
    assert(0 <= i && i < t->n); // terminal
    if (t->node[i].pix == -1) {
        done = huffman_insert(t, i); // Unseen terminal node.
    } else if (!t->complete && t->depth < 63 && t->node[i].freq < UINT64_MAX - 1) {
        t->node[i].freq++;
        huffman_frequency_changed(t, i);
    } else {
        // ignore future frequency updates
        t->complete = 1;
        done = false;
    }
    return done;
}

static inline double huffman_entropy(const huffman_tree* t) {
    // Shannon entropy
    double total = 0;
    double entropy = 0.0;
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < t->n; i++) { total += (double)t->node[i].freq; }
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < t->n; i++) {
        if (t->node[i].freq > 0) {
            double p_i = (double)t->node[i].freq / total;
            entropy += p_i * log2(p_i);
        }
    }
    return -entropy;
}

static inline void huffman_init(huffman_tree* t,
                                huffman_node nodes[],
                                const size_t count) {
    assert(7 <= count && count < INT32_MAX); // must pow(2, bits_per_symbol) * 2 - 1
    const int32_t n = (int32_t)(count + 1) / 2;
    assert(n > 4 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0); // must be power of 2
    memset(&t->stats, 0x00, sizeof(t->stats));
    t->node = nodes;
    t->n = n;
    const int32_t root = n * 2 - 1;
    t->next = root - 1; // next non-terminal node
    t->depth = 0;
    t->complete = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        t->node[i] = (huffman_node){
            .freq = 0, .pix = -1, .lix = -1, .rix = -1, .bits = 0, .path = 0
        };
    }
}

// Deflate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate

static void squeeze_deflate_init(squeeze_type* s) {
    uint8_t  j = 0;
    uint16_t n = squeeze_len_base[j] + (1u << squeeze_len_xb[j]);
    for (int16_t i = 3; i < countof(s->len_index); i++) {
        if (i == n) {
            j++;
            n = squeeze_len_base[j] + (1u << squeeze_len_xb[j]);
        }
        s->len_index[i] = j;
    }
    assert(j == countof(squeeze_len_base) - 1);
    j = 0;
    n = squeeze_pos_base[j] + (1u << squeeze_pos_xb[j]);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < countof(s->pos_index); i++) {
        if (i == n) {
            j++;
            n = squeeze_pos_base[j] + (1u << squeeze_pos_xb[j]);
        }
        s->pos_index[i] = j;
    }
    assert(j == countof(squeeze_pos_base) - 1);
}

// Squeeze https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78

static void squeeze_init(squeeze_type* s) {
    huffman_init(&s->lit, s->lit_nodes, countof(s->lit_nodes));
    huffman_init(&s->pos, s->pos_nodes, countof(s->pos_nodes));
}

static inline void squeeze_write_bit(squeeze_type* s, bool bit) {
    if (s->error == 0) {
        bitstream_write_bit(s->bs, bit);
        s->error = s->bs->error;
    }
}

static inline void squeeze_write_bits(squeeze_type* s,
                                      uint64_t b64, uint8_t bits) {
    if (s->error == 0) {
        bitstream_write_bits(s->bs, b64, bits);
        s->error = s->bs->error;
    }
}

static inline void squeeze_write_huffman(squeeze_type* s, huffman_tree* t,
                                         int32_t i) {
    assert(t != null && t->node != null);
    assert(0 <= i && i < t->n); // leaf symbol (literal)
    assert(1 <= t->node[i].bits && t->node[i].bits < 64);
    squeeze_write_bits(s, t->node[i].path, (uint8_t)t->node[i].bits);
    (void)huffman_inc_frequency(t, i); // after the path is written
    // (void) because inability to update frequency is OK here
}

static inline void squeeze_flush(squeeze_type* s) {
    if (s->error == 0) {
        bitstream_flush(s->bs);
        s->error = s->bs->error;
    }
}

static void squeeze_write_header(bitstream* bs, uint64_t bytes) {
    enum { bits64 = sizeof(uint64_t) * 8 };
    bitstream_write_bits(bs, (uint64_t)bytes, bits64);
}

static uint8_t squeeze_log2_of_pow2(uint64_t pow2) {
    assert(pow2 > 0 && (pow2 & (pow2 - 1)) == 0);
    if (pow2 > 0 && (pow2 & (pow2 - 1)) == 0) {
        uint8_t bit = 0;
        while (pow2 >>= 1) { bit++; }
        return bit;
    } else {
        return 0xFF; // error
    }
}

static inline void squeeze_encode_literal(squeeze_type* s, const uint16_t lit) {
    assert(0 <= lit && lit <= squeeze_deflate_sym_max);
    if (s->lit.node[lit].bits == 0) {
        assert(s->lit.node[squeeze_lit_nyt].bits != 0);
        squeeze_write_huffman(s, &s->lit, squeeze_lit_nyt);
        squeeze_write_bits(s, lit, 9);
        if (!huffman_insert(&s->lit, lit)) { s->error = E2BIG; }
    } else {
        squeeze_write_huffman(s, &s->lit, lit);
    }
}

static inline void squeeze_encode_len(squeeze_type* s, const uint16_t len) {
    assert(3 <= len && len < sizeof(s->len_index));
    uint8_t  i = s->len_index[len];
    uint16_t b = squeeze_len_base[i];
    uint8_t  x = squeeze_len_xb[i];
    squeeze_encode_literal(s, (uint16_t)(squeeze_deflate_sym_min + i));
    assert(b <= len && len - b <= (uint16_t)(1u << x));
    if (x > 0) { squeeze_write_bits(s, (len - b), x); }
}

static inline void squeeze_encode_pos(squeeze_type* s, const uint16_t pos) {
    assert(0 <= pos && pos <= 0x7FFF);
    uint8_t  i = s->pos_index[pos];
    uint16_t b = squeeze_pos_base[i];
    uint8_t  x = squeeze_pos_xb[i];
    if (s->pos.node[i].bits == 0) {
        assert(s->pos.node[squeeze_pos_nyt].bits != 0);
        squeeze_write_huffman(s, &s->pos, squeeze_pos_nyt);
        squeeze_write_bits(s, i, 5); // 0..29
        if (!huffman_insert(&s->pos, i)) { s->error = E2BIG; }
    } else {
        squeeze_write_huffman(s, &s->pos, i);
    }
    assert(b <= pos && pos - b <= (uint16_t)(1u << x));
    if (x > 0) { squeeze_write_bits(s, (pos - b), x); }
}

static void squeeze_compress(squeeze_type* s, bitstream* bs,
                             const uint8_t* data, uint64_t bytes,
                             uint16_t window) {
    s->bs = bs;
    if (!huffman_insert(&s->lit, squeeze_lit_nyt)) { s->error = EINVAL; }
    if (!huffman_insert(&s->pos, squeeze_pos_nyt)) { s->error = EINVAL; }
    squeeze_deflate_init(s);
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < bytes && s->error == 0) {
        size_t len = 0;
        size_t pos = 0;
        if (i >= 1) {
            size_t j = i - 1;
            size_t min_j = i >= window ? i - window + 1 : 0;
            for (;;) {
                assert((i - j) < window);
                const size_t n = bytes - i;
                size_t k = 0;
                while (k < n && data[j + k] == data[i + k] && k < squeeze_deflate_len_max) {
                    k++;
                }
                if (k >= squeeze_deflate_len_min && k > len) {
                    len = k;
                    pos = i - j;
                    if (len == squeeze_deflate_len_max) { break; }
                }
                if (j == min_j) { break; }
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (len >= squeeze_deflate_len_min) {
            assert(0 < pos && pos <= 0x7FFF);
            squeeze_encode_len(s, (uint16_t)len);
            squeeze_encode_pos(s, (uint16_t)pos);
            i += len;
        } else {
            squeeze_encode_literal(s, data[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    squeeze_flush(s);
}

static inline uint64_t squeeze_read_bit(squeeze_type* s) {
    bool bit = 0;
    if (s->error == 0) {
        bit = bitstream_read_bit(s->bs);
        s->error = s->bs->error;
    }
    return bit;
}

static inline uint64_t squeeze_read_bits(squeeze_type* s, uint32_t n) {
    assert(n <= 64);
    uint64_t bits = 0;
    if (s->error == 0) {
        bits = bitstream_read_bits(s->bs, n);
    }
    return bits;
}

static inline uint64_t squeeze_read_huffman(squeeze_type* s, huffman_tree* t) {
    const int32_t m = t->n * 2 - 1;
    int32_t i = m - 1; // root
    bool bit = squeeze_read_bit(s);
    while (s->error == 0) {
        i = bit ? t->node[i].rix : t->node[i].lix;
        assert(0 <= i && i < m);
        if (t->node[i].lix < 0 && t->node[i].rix < 0) { break; } // leaf
        bit = squeeze_read_bit(s);
    }
    assert(0 <= i && i < t->n); // leaf symbol (literal)
    (void)huffman_inc_frequency(t, i);
    // (void) because inability to update frequency is OK here
    return (uint64_t)i;
}

static void squeeze_read_header(bitstream* bs, uint64_t *bytes) {
    uint64_t b = bitstream_read_bits(bs, sizeof(uint64_t) * 8);
    if (bs->error == 0) { *bytes = b; }
}

static uint16_t squeeze_read_length(squeeze_type* s, uint16_t lit) {
    const uint8_t base = (uint8_t)(lit - squeeze_deflate_sym_min);
    if (base >= countof(squeeze_len_base)) {
        s->error = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        const uint8_t bits = squeeze_len_xb[base];
        if (bits != 0) {
            uint64_t extra = squeeze_read_bits(s, bits);
            assert(squeeze_len_base[base] + extra <= UINT16_MAX);
            return s->error == 0 ?
                (uint16_t)squeeze_len_base[base] + (uint16_t)extra : 0;
        } else {
            return squeeze_len_base[base];
        }
    }
}

static uint32_t squeeze_read_pos(squeeze_type* s) {
    uint32_t pos = 0;
    uint64_t base = squeeze_read_huffman(s, &s->pos);
    if (s->error == 0 && base == squeeze_pos_nyt) {
        base = squeeze_read_bits(s, 5);
        if (s->error == 0) {
            if (!huffman_insert(&s->pos, (int32_t)base)) {
                s->error = E2BIG;
            }
        }
    }
    if (s->error == 0 && base >= countof(squeeze_pos_base)) {
        s->error = EINVAL;
    } else {
        pos = squeeze_pos_base[base];
    }
    if (s->error == 0) {
        uint8_t bits  = squeeze_pos_xb[base];
        if (bits > 0) {
            uint64_t extra = squeeze_read_bits(s, bits);
            if (s->error == 0) { pos += (uint32_t)extra; }
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

static void squeeze_decompress(squeeze_type* s, bitstream* bs,
                               uint8_t* data, uint64_t bytes) {
    s->bs = bs;
    if (!huffman_insert(&s->lit, squeeze_lit_nyt)) { s->error = EINVAL; }
    if (!huffman_insert(&s->pos, squeeze_pos_nyt)) { s->error = EINVAL; }
    squeeze_deflate_init(s);
    size_t i = 0; // output b64[i]
    while (i < bytes && s->error == 0) {
        uint64_t lit = squeeze_read_huffman(s, &s->lit);
        if (s->error != 0) { break; }
        if (lit == squeeze_lit_nyt) {
            lit = squeeze_read_bits(s, 9);
            if (s->error != 0) { break; }
            // TODO: error if insert fails
            if (!huffman_insert(&s->lit, (int32_t)lit)) {
                s->error = E2BIG;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (lit <= 0xFF) {
            data[i] = (uint8_t)lit;
            i++;
        } else {
            assert(squeeze_deflate_sym_min <= lit && lit < squeeze_lit_nyt);
            if (squeeze_deflate_sym_min <= lit && lit <= squeeze_lit_nyt) {
                uint32_t len = squeeze_read_length(s, (uint16_t)lit);
                if (s->error != 0) { break; }
                assert(squeeze_deflate_len_min <= len && len <= squeeze_deflate_len_max);
                if (squeeze_deflate_len_min <= len && len <= squeeze_deflate_len_max) {
                    uint32_t pos = squeeze_read_pos(s);
                    if (s->error != 0) { break; }
                    assert(0 < pos && pos <= 0x7FFF);
                    if (0 < pos && pos <= 0x7FFF) {
                        // memcpy() cannot be used on overlapped regions
                        // because it may read more than one byte at a time.
                        uint8_t* d = data - (size_t)pos;
                        const size_t n = i + (size_t)len;
                        while (i < n) { data[i] = d[i]; i++; }
                    } else {
                        s->error = EINVAL;
                    }
                } else {
                    s->error = EINVAL;
                }
            } else {
                s->error = EINVAL;
            }
        }
    }
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" { // avoid mangling of global variable "squeeze" by C++ compilers
#endif

squeeze_interface squeeze = {
    .init         = squeeze_init,
    .write_header = squeeze_write_header,
    .compress     = squeeze_compress,
    .read_header  = squeeze_read_header,
    .decompress   = squeeze_decompress,
};

#if defined(__cplusplus)
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif // squeeze_implementation



#define null ((void*)0) // like null_ptr better than NULL (0) ??? Use C23's nullptr? Why not Just use NULL? 2) I'd have expected all the enums and macros to be in all caps. 3) Don't cast the return of malloc() and family. C doesn't require a cast, C++ does. 4) Now where does errno_t come from? Some Annex-K of the C11 standard addition?


@Harith Reviews go in answers, not in comments ;-)

@Mast I did not have time for a review, so just made some remarks. :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899757/how-can-i-use-nullptr-for-null-pointers-prior-to-c23

Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. What to do after the question has been answered.

Not sure why you've replaced several separate "header files" with only a single file (that may or may not contain all the earlier code.) Its apparent filename, now, is totally misleading...
One massive bug is defining data and coding functions in a header file. This contravenes conventional C coding practices, and may be why no one feels like addressing this posting.

Review
Poorly coded.
If this is your code, it exhibits familiarity with C coding syntax and practices. No reason has been provided to depart so grotesquely from C coding conventions.

Can you elaborate please. I want to understand where did I break C coding conventions, how and how to improve.

Be self-reliant. Refer to "Chapter 4.5 Header Files" of the K&R bible called "The C Programming Language" for elaboration.
